# Read in input from user based on initial input

Tags: ruby

I have written the following code in Ruby that takes input from a user regarding plane and flight details and displays the user inputs as an array in the terminal. However, the program is reading in four times. What changes can I make so that the program prompts the user on how many planes they want to enter an then read in that many times? For example, if the user enters 3 then the program reads in input 3 times. I am also getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
2: from plane.rb:68:in `<main>'
1: from plane.rb:65:in`main'
plane.rb:56:in `print_planes': undefined method`length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
require './input_functions'
class Plane
    attr_accessor :id, :number, :origin, :destination

    def initialize (id, number, origin, destination)
        @id=id
        @number = number
        @origin = origin
        @destination = destination
    end 
end 
def read_plane()

    plane_id = read_integer("Enter plane id:")
    plane_number = read_string("Enter flight name:")
    plane_origin = read_string("Enter origin airport:")
    plane_destination = read_string("Enter destination airport:")
    plane = Plane.new()
    plane.id = plane_id
    plane.number = plane_number
    plane.origin = plane_origin
    plane.destination = plane_destination   
    return plane
end

def read_planes()
    planes=Array.new()
    count=0
    while (count<4)
        planes<<read_plane()
        count+=1
    end     
end

def print_plane(plane)
    puts ("Plane id "+plane.id)
    puts ("Flight "+plane.number)
    puts ("Origin "+plane.origin)
    puts ("Destination "+plane.destination)

end

def print_planes(planes)
    index = 0
    while (index<planes.length)
        puts planes[index]
        index+=1
    end 

end

def main()
    planes = read_planes()
    print_planes(planes)
end

main()
```

Comment: If *planes* is `nil`, then it won't have a #length method. You need to figure out under what circumstances your planes object is assigned `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_planes()
  planes=Array.new()
  planes_count = read_integer("How many planes do you want to enter?")
  count=0
  while (count<planes_count)
    planes<<read_plane()
    count+=1
  end     
end
```

This is a fix and should work, but it's not a very ruby-ish way to solve this. May I suggest `.times`, and `.map`?

```
def read_planes
  planes_count = read_integer("How many planes do you want to enter?")
  planes_count.times.map do
    read_plane
  end  
end
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But now I am getting the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
2: from plane.rb:68:in `<main>'
1: from plane.rb:65:in `main'
plane.rb:56:in `print_planes': undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: I think it's because you're not returning planes from read_planes. The code I provided (with map) would do that, but while that you're using currently only returns nil. Either return planes after the while loop or use map.